# performing calculation in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

dear all..i have some data at DB.

```
name        Range
bla     123x9901-123x0000      //it means range 9901 until 10000 = 100
bla     123v0001-123v0100      // 10001-10100 = 100
```

i want the result like:

```
   name         Qty  
   bla          200
```

i counting them use:

```
SELECT................
      IF(RIGHT(Range,4) = "0000",10000,RIGHT(Range,4)) - MID(Range,5,4) + 1 AS Qty
FROM mytable GROUP BY name;
```

but the result:

```
name      Qty
bla       100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT name,
         SUM(IF(RIGHT(Range,4) = "0000",10000, RIGHT(Range,4)) - MID(Range,5,4) + 1) AS Qty
    FROM mytable
GROUP BY name;
```

...gives me:

```
name    Qty  
-------------
bla     200
```

Comment: that's great..simple answer but usefull.